# error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl(решения по схожим не нашлось)

Tags: c++

Function.h

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include "time.h"

using namespace std;


template<class T> void FillArr(T *arr, const int size, const T min, const T max, const int order);
template<class T> T RandNext(const T min, const T max, const int order);
template<class T> void PrintArr(const T *arr, const int size);
template<class T> void SearchMinElement(const T *arr, const int size);
template<class T> void SearchMaxElement(const T *arr, const int size);
template<class T> void SortBubble(const T *arr, const int size);
```

Function.cpp

```
#include "Function.h"
template<class T> T RandNext(const T min, const T max, const int order)
{
    return (T)(rand() % (((int)max - (int)min + 1)*order) + (int)min*order) / order;
}
template<class T> void FillArr(T *arr, const int size, const T min, const T max, const int order)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        *(arr + i) = RandNext(min, max, order);
    }
}
template<class T> void PrintArr(const T *arr, const int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        cout << *(arr + i) << "  ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
template<class T> void SearchMinElement(const T * arr, const int size)
{
    T minElement = *(arr + 0);
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        if (minElement < *(arr + i))
        {
            minElement = *(arr + i);
        }
    }
    cout << "minElement: " << minElement << endl;
}
template<class T> void SearchMaxElement(const T * arr, const int size)
{
    T maxElement = *(arr + 0);
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        if (maxElement > *(arr + i))
        {
            maxElement = *(arr + i);
        }
    }
    cout << "maxElement: " << maxElement << endl;
}

template<class T> void SortBubble(const T * arr, const int size)
{
    T temp;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < size - i - 1; ++j)
        {
            if (*(arr + j) > *(arr + j + 1))
            {
                temp = *(arr + j);
                *(arr + j) = *(arr + j + 1);
                *(arr + j + 1) = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Main

```
#include "Function.h"
int main()
{
    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));

    int SIZE = 10;
    int *myArray = new int[SIZE]{};

    FillArr(myArray, 10, 10, 20, 1);
    PrintArr(myArray, SIZE);

    return 0;
}
```

А вот собственно ГВОЗДЬ вопроса, уже битый час не могу разбраться..

```
1>------ Build started: Project: FirstProject, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  Prog.cpp
1>  Function.cpp
1>  Generating Code...
1>Prog.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl FillArr<int>(int *,int,int,int,int)" (??$FillArr@H@@YAXPAHHHHH@Z) referenced in function _main
1>Prog.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl PrintArr<int>(int const *,int)" (??$PrintArr@H@@YAXPBHH@Z) referenced in function _main
1>c:\users\mazur\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\FirstProject\Debug\FirstProject.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: ... Ну вы же определения вынесли в `cpp`, а это шаблонные функции, они должны быть `inline` либо в конце файла `Function.h` напишите `#include <Function.cpp>`.

Comment: Проблемма в том, что я не использую классы и я не могу предсказать какой ТИП мне понадобится, #include <Function.cpp> написал, не работает

Comment: Помогло, спасибо большое, за ваш ответ, только не #include <Function.cpp> , а #include "Function.cpp", все идеально, еще раз спасибо